# Moving Domain Controller Guests between Hyper-V Hosts

Tags: hyper-v, domain-controller

We're moving our domain controller to a new Hyper-V host. I read it on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2cae85b-41ac-497f-8cd1-5fbaa6740ffe%28v=ws.10%29#backup_and_restore_considerations_for_virtualized_domain_controllers) about not using export on a VM running as DC (although I saw a [lot of](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/wn/winserverhyperv/thread/f2da9f95-0eeb-436f-b10c-7061e962d976) [answers](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/wn/winserverhyperv/thread/f2da9f95-0eeb-436f-b10c-7061e962d976) on TechNet suggesting doing so to move DC). What we plan to do is shutdown the VM, move the VHD to the new Hyper-V host, then create a new VM using that VHD. I don't think USN rollback would occur since it's like shutting down the VM and starting it back up. We have another Hyper-V host with a DC guest that will be running during the migration. All the hosts and VMs are running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Is it a good way to move virtualize DC b/t hosts? If not, how should I proceed?

Comment: As a reminder its always a good idea to have a physical DC somewhere on the network to handle virtual downtime that is inevitable.

Comment: We have two DCs running on two Hyper-V hosts to handle downtime. Should we still have one more physical DC?

Comment: Yes. For instance, if you're Hyper-V Hosts happen to be part of a cluster and both DCs are offline, good luck getting the cluster to start properly, let alone access storage devices with no logon servers present on the network.  It's OK to virtualize most of them, just have a physical box sitting arround that can help when needed. Saves lots of trouble later on. Plus MSFT recommends it.

Comment: I see. The hosts are domain-joined by not clustered. I'll definitely consider having a small box as a physical DC. Thanks for the advice =)

Comment: Yea, there are other services as well that may rely on authentication on Hyper-V host startup, so certainly something to look into.

Comment: Did you use shutdown, export, import, power on??
Does the domain controller /active directory works fine??
Thanks.
Goose

Comment: No I didn't export/import. I shutdown the VM, move the VHD to the new server, create a new VM with the same specs and the existing VHD. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have moved several DCs in the way you described and it works rather well. Don't forget to remove the old network interface after re-creating the VM on the new host.

Answer (score 0):

Note the IP Address assign to network card. Remove the old NIC and add new one. Assign the same IP that was assigned to old NIC.